# gnome-tweaks fontsize increase does not work with non-system apps

Tags: gnome, fonts, text

I need to increase the font-size of my OS and everything else in general (Ubuntu 20.04 gnome). When I do this using gnome-tweaks, it works for things like nautilus and some other gnome apps but not for third party softwares (eg. xmgrace, gnuplot, matlab etc.) Kindly let me know if there is any solution for this problem.

Sorry if this has already been answered before.

Comment: A Gnome tweak works with Gnome aps and features.

Answer (score 0):

Third party apps may be using dedicated graphical toolkits that do not obey the font scaling setting. For QT5 applications, one may change the font size using Qt5 configuration tool. For other toolkits or versions thereof, there may or may not be tools or tricks to change the font scale. Eventually, your only option to render any application at a decent size may be to run at a lower screen resolution.

Comment: Nice to see you back online :-)

Comment: @heynnema back from a holiday break ;)